# Ruby deep merge with different hash types

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm struggling with this problem and I can't figure out how to do that. Let's suppose I have two hashes:

```
hash1 = { "address" => "address", "phone" => "phone }
hash2 = { "info" => { "address" => "x", "phone" => "y"}, 
          "contact_info" => { "info" => { "address" => "x", "phone" => "y"} }}
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
{ "info" => { "address" => "address", "phone" => "phone"},
  "contact_info" => { "info" => { "address" => "address", "phone" => "phone"} }}
```

I've tried `Hash#deep_merge` but it does not solve my problem. What I need is something that will merge all keys and values anywhere in the second hash whatever it's structure is.

How can I do that? Any clues?

Comment: Your expression is not a valid Ruby object. Your sentences are not valid English. Furthermore, it does not have any question in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to recursively merge hash1? Maybe this:

```
class Hash

  def deep_merge_each_key(o)
    self.keys.each do |k|
      if o.has_key?(k)
        self[k] = o[k]
      elsif self[k].is_a?(Hash)
        self[k].deep_merge_each_key(o)
      end
    end
    self
  end
end

h1 = {"address"=>"address", "phone"=>"phone"}
h2 = {
  "info" => { "address" => "x", "phone" => "y"},
  "contact_info" => { "info" => { "address" => "x", "phone" => "y"} }
}

puts h2.deep_merge_each_key(h1).inspect

# => {"info"=>{"address"=>"address", "phone"=>"phone"}, "contact_info"=>{"info"=>{"address"=>"address", "phone"=>"phone"}}}
```